My computer crash unexpectedly
I got few problem with my computer. I have an dell G15 5530 with an nvidia RTX 3050. I got problems like:
-don't boot (I can't even reach the part when I need to enter my disk decrypt password)
-don't boot fully: got stuck during the boot
-randomly freeze: my laptop freeze at random moment. I can be writing some text in libreoffice, watching youtube and more and suddenly, my computer crash (I can move the mouse but my pc didn't respond to click)
-freeze when I plug the power in and when I plug it out
I have already reinstalled my computer two times, all the programe are up to date and I have used the command: ubuntu-drivers autoinstall, but still the same problem. Strange point: my computer work fine with tails.
I’m using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, 64 but, with gnome 42.9

Maybe tell us what operating system you’re using?!

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, 64 but, with gnome 42.9

Ok - I’ve edited that in to your question.
